# Разделить изображение по горизонтали

Tags: python, opencv

Уважаемые, как разделить изображение по горизонтали на две равные части?
Python

```
im = cv2.imread('/home/alexander/empty.jpg')
dimensions = im.shape


width_cutoff = dimensions[1] // 2
s1 = im[:, :width_cutoff]
s2 = im[:,width_cutoff :]

cv2.imwrite("p1.png", s1)
cv2.imwrite("p2.png", s2)
```

Это код,который делит изображение по вертикали на две равные части по вертикали и сохраняет эти части как два отдельных изображения. Как сделать также,но по вертикали? Спасибо

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? приведите свой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо строк:

```
width_cutoff = dimensions[1] // 2
s1 = im[:, :width_cutoff]
s2 = im[:,width_cutoff :]
```

написать:

```
height_cutoff = dimensions[0] // 2
s1 = im[:heigt_cutoff,:]
s2 = im[height_cutoff:, :]
```

все остальное оставьте так же.